# PHP exec() returning empty array (no output) when executing java -jar command

Tags: java, php, apache, jar

I have a working web php app. I'm working on win 7 and using apache.

Now I'm trying to execute this java command in php and display result on site:

```
exec("java -jar C:\webroot\ipt\themes\ipt\views\site\Skills.jar 5 10 5.5 10 2 5 8 3 10 6 11 2 15 4", $output);

    for ($index = 0; $index < count($output); $index++) {
        echo $output[$index]." ";
    }
```

However $output is an empty array - no output.
I'm not getting any error or crash. Output is only a basic string.
I tried to enter this same command in cmd and it work as it should - returning expected output.

So I tried different command to see if it's not problem with exec(), so I tried 'ipconfig' which displayed output on site flawlesly.

Because of this I think it has something to do with either PHP or Apache (or both).

I searched for some similar problems of other people and tried:

- entering full path of java to the command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin\java - jar ... - didn't work
- to change permisions to the .jar file to full access (including parent directories) - didn't work.

So I want to ask if someone doesn't know solution to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: did you try this command on your shell / cmd ?

Comment: is safe mode enabled? http://php.net/manual/es/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are able to run this command without any problems in your console directly.

Change your `exec` to the following:

`exec("java -jar C:\\webroot\\ipt\\themes\\ipt\\views\\site\\Skills.jar 5 10 5.5 10 2 5 8 3 10 6 11 2 15 4 2>&1", $output);`

Comment: Thank you. That worked, but just a small question: what does this '2>&1' part mean?

Comment: It ensures that the output goes to the PHP handler that is handling the shell execution.